# how to fix the width of the bar chart in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am adding dynamically bars in right side and need scroll. How can I fix a width of the bar so if i add more it will show horizontal scroll.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Short question equals short answer

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Comment: The barWidth is not fixed the whole width adjusting automatically by the plugin

Comment: Set it to fixed size then

Comment: Thats my question how to set?

Comment: @sibaspage With css? `width: whatever`